# How to avoid warning "You access a signal or memo outside a reactive tracking context"

Tags: rust, leptos

I have an async action which alters data in an external api (POST request). When the request has finished, then I need to refetch data from this api, in order to reflect the changes in the view. But when I call `my_resource.refetch()` inside the action, I get this warning in the web console:

> At
> .../.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/leptos_reactive-0.3.0/src/resource.rs:910:25,
> you access a signal or memo (defined at
> .../.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/leptos_reactive-0.3.0/src/resource.rs:339:18)
> outside a reactive tracking context. This might mean your app is not
> responding to changes in signal values in the way you expect.

How to get rid of it?

Here is a minimal working example  which reflects the problem (when clicking on the button, the warning appears):

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};

use leptos::*;

/// Let's pretend we have some data which can accessed and modified via an external API:
static EXTERNAL_DATA: AtomicUsize = AtomicUsize::new(1);

/// Alters the API data.
pub async fn alter_external_data() {
    EXTERNAL_DATA.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst); // Should be async
}

/// Gets the API data.
pub async fn fetch_external_data(n: i32) -> String {
    n.to_string().repeat(EXTERNAL_DATA.load(Ordering::SeqCst)) // Should be async
}

#[component()]
pub fn App(cx: Scope) -> impl IntoView {
    let (read_number, set_number) = create_signal(cx, 1);

    // `async_data` depends on `read_number`, but must be refreshed each time the button below has
    // been clicked, because the external data has been altered.
    let async_data = create_local_resource(cx, read_number, |n| async move {
        fetch_external_data(n).await
    });

    // Action which alters the external data. Then `async_data` has to be refetched.
    let alter_external_data_action = create_action(cx, move |_: &()| async move {
        alter_external_data().await;
        async_data.refetch(); // THIS TRIGGERS A WARNING
    });

    view! { cx,
        <p>
            "Fetched data: "
            {move || async_data.read(cx)}
        </p>

        <p>
            "N = "
            <input type="number"
                prop:value=read_number
                on:change=move |ev| set_number(event_target_value(&ev).parse().unwrap())
            />
        </p>

        <p>
            <button on:click=move |_| alter_external_data_action.dispatch(())>
                "Alter external data"
            </button>
        </p>
    }
}

fn main() {
    mount_to_body(|cx| view! { cx, <App/> })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The earlier answer is probably correct, but I thought I might as well give a more general workaround to avoid that warning.

There is a function in the leptos_reactive crate called `SpecialNonReactiveZone::enter`, which should mark the current function as a reactive zone, disabling that warning.
You'll also need to add `leptos_reactive` as a dependency for you crate as well.

Please note that this is meant to be an **internal feature**, so don't rely on this too much.

```rust
use leptos_reactive::SpecialNonReactiveZone;

#[component]
pub fn App(cx: Scope) -> impl IntoView {

    ...

    let alter_external_data_action = create_action(cx, move |_: &()| async move {
        SpecialNonReactiveZone::enter();
        alter_external_data().await;
        async_data.refetch(); // THIS TRIGGERS A WARNING
    });

    ...

}
```

**This is not completely correct yet though!** As this is an internal function you should first store the value of `SpecialNonReactiveZone::is_inside()` and update the value with an if statement at the end, which will ensure that the warning will function correctly in other places.

But if you **don't care** about reenabling the warning and you're fine with potentially disabling it in other places it's perfectly fine to use the code above.

Updated code:

```rust
use leptos_reactive::SpecialNonReactiveZone;

#[component]
pub fn App(cx: Scope) -> impl IntoView {

    ...

    let alter_external_data_action = create_action(cx, move |_: &()| async move {
        let is_reactive = SpecialNonReactiveZone::is_inside();
        SpecialNonReactiveZone::enter();

        alter_external_data().await;
        async_data.refetch();

        if (!is_reactive) {
            SpecialNonReactiveZone::exit()
        }
    });

    ...

}
```

It should work like this, I haven't tested it though. So if it doesn't work feel free to complain!

Comment: You forgot to add `leptos_reactive::SpecialNonReactiveZone::exit();` at the end:) Indeed it's working. But it's a hidden feature, and it's not easy to use because it does not track nested calls: `SpecialNonReactiveZone::is_inside()` should be stored before, and the correct state should be restored at the end with an `if` statement... A bit verbose for what it's supposed to do:)

Comment: Yea that would be the correct way to do it. I use it more as a very rough way to just entirely disable that warning, so I didn't care to reenable it. Updated the answer to clarify this :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using an effect which depends on the action's value:

```
let alter_external_data_action = create_action(cx, move |_: &()| async move {
    alter_external_data().await;
    // REMOVE THIS CALL:
    // async_data.refetch();
});

// ADD THIS EFFECT:
let resp = alter_external_data_action.value();
create_effect(cx, move |_| if resp().is_some() {
    async_data.refetch()
});
```

EDIT: This generic method can be used in order to reduce code verbosity:

```
pub fn refetch_resource_after_action<RS, RT, AI, AO>(
    cx: Scope,
    resource: Resource<RS, RT>,
    action: Action<AI, AO>,
)
where
    RS: Clone,
    AO: Clone,
{
    let action_value = action.value();
    create_effect(cx, move |_| if action_value().is_some() {
        resource.refetch()
    });
}
```

Now in the solution above, instead of adding the effect manually, you can simply write:

```
refetch_resource_after_action(cx, node_content, alter_external_data_action);
```